# android- How to see the map using maps lib

Tags: android, maps

I implemented the app that displays the map. and it shows the particular location using latitude and longitude. but it shows an empty map.how to see the map. please can anybody help me.
[image]

```
code
```

public class mapsdemo extends MapActivity 
 {

```
MapView mapView;
GeoPoint gp;
MapController mc;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    List mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    double lat = 17.385044;
    double longi = 78.486671;

    gp = new GeoPoint((int) (lat *1E6),(int) (longi *1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem =  new OverlayItem(gp, "Hello", "I'm in Hyd");                                                                      
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);        
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.animateTo(gp);
    mc.setZoom(13);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {      
    return false;
}
```

}

```
main.xml
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

 < com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:apiKey="00YCOT71Vu0btHPPlbIR9uvF0-l4mcAVT9_6HMw"   
                 android:id="@+id/mapView"  
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"        
                 />
< /LinearLayout>

manifeast

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.maps.demo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    < uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".mapsdemo"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: i posted the main.xml. please refer it

Comment: map api key is generated by your PC or any another PC ?

Comment: our pc only. i created using this video tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgr4l1nsFdU

Comment: is it unique for every pc? How many api key's we are generated for single pc?

Comment: If you're just using the default debug keystore, it'll be different on each PC unless you explicitly share the keystore across computers or set the eclipse plugin to use a specific keystore.

Comment: our video link is default or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a signature mismatch. Make sure that you registered your private key from the keystore used to package your application with Google at the [maps API signup page](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html) and ensure the key that is issued is in your layout file for the MapView.

Comment: The maps api signup page that I linked in my answer shows the keytool command for getting the MD5 fingerprint of your private key. Just make sure that you're using the right keystore (if you're using the eclipse android plugin and haven't changed any of the default settings, it'll be in the .android directory within your home folder).